# Problem with bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

![Bibliography][1]

How do I remove RefWorks quote at the beginning?
I used these commands:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may want to have a look at our [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: At this stage you don't have enough reputation points to post an image, but you can insert a link and a user with sufficient rights will then edit your question.

Comment: As to your question: `\nocite{*}` will list all your reserences contained in the `bib` file you load. Are you trying to print all *except* one entry? Quick fix: you could for instance comment out the superfluous entry in the `bib` file for instance. (That works if you don't use that entry elsewhere.)

Comment: I suppose there is a reference to RefWorks at the beginning of your bibliography? You could edit your *.bib file with a text editor and remove the reference to RefWorks in this file

Comment: please use a site like `https://imgur.com/` I can't see your screen shot on facebook.

Comment: I also took a look at bibtex files produced by refworks. The entries start like this `@article{RefWorks:4` but `RefWorks` doesn't show up in the bibliography. So can you tell us what problem exactly you are experiencing?